# Using Eventuate framework

Tags: java, spring, events, spring-boot

I have juste starting using evetn
I'm playing with some event sourcing things. This is the first time that I use that concept. After googling I found **eventuate** which is a java framework that helps you to implement that concept. I get started with that example:
**https://github.com/eventuate-examples/eventuate-examples-java-spring-todo-list**

I tested it and it looks very good. In that project there is many spring-boot project. Every microservice is a spring-boot project.

My question is How I can do in my IDE, eclipse, if I want to develop some services?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot projects are Maven build , so even you can add Maven dependencies and plugins/properties in the project for eventuate. Eventuate is a framework that has integration with Gradle and Maven project ( Visit http://eventuate.io/docs/javav2/maven-gradle-config.html ). For your refrence , I am adding some dependencies that might be help to you :

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.eventuate.client.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>eventuate-client-java-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${eventuateClientVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.eventuate.client.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>eventuate-client-java-test-util</artifactId>
        <version>${eventuateClientVersion}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.eventuate.local.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>eventuate-local-java-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${eventuateLocalVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.eventuate.local.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>eventuate-local-java-embedded-cdc-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>${eventuateLocalVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Make sure to add this client library :

```
   <properties>
      <eventuateClientVersion>0.11.0.RELEASE</eventuateClientVersion>
      <eventuateLocalVersion>0.5.0.RELEASE</eventuateLocalVersion>
   </properties>
```